# RST + Sphinx: How to configure search to make it work differently?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs

I have a documentation project using sphinx. I have two questions regarding the search behaviour:

**Question 1:** When I search for something in the docs, I get rst output. How can I prevent that and make it more human readable? For example look at the following screenshot.

[image]

**Question 2:** When I click on a search item, sphinx automatically highlights the terms. I do not want that to happen. How can I prevent it from applying highlights.  For example look at the following screenshot.

[image: Auto highlight after search]

Comment: Regarding question 2, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48771802/407651

Comment: Regarding question 1: I thought that something had been done to fix this, but I'm not sure what to expect. See https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/1618. What version of Sphinx do you use?

Comment: By the way, in the future please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Sorry about that and thanks for helping out.

I am using sphinx version 1.8.3

Comment: Nope. I am still with those problems. I am not able to figure it out

Comment: Sorry I was a bit wrong. I was able to override the css to fix the highlighting. I was running into another problem with highlighting, which is why I said that. So yes, your suggestion on css fix did help. Thanks for that

Comment: Done! Regarding 1, I had not realised that this was something that was never fixed for such a long time. I mean sphinx is such a popular docs generator. The search is getting fixed only in version 2.

Comment: Please remove "question 2" and turn this into a question that is only about "question 1".